# What is Top-level types and Nested-level Types?

Tags: c#, .net

What is Top-level types and Nested-level Types in C#?

Comment: This is a terribly vague question. Look at this for all the info you need on Nested Types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdz1bea9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top-level types are defined directly inside a namespace:

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar {} // top-level class
}
```

[Nested types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are defined *inside another class or struct*:

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
        class Baz {} // nested type
    }
}
```